# How is it that multiple pipe() methods can be chained?

Tags: jquery

I've been struggling with some JQuery code from MS, I don't quite understand the following code:

```
$.when(......)
.pipe(a())
.pipe(b())
.pipe(c());

a = function(){new $.Deferred().resolve();};
b = function(){d();};
c = ... //some code
```

The code actually works very well, but I think neither a() nor b() is returning a deferred or promised object, so how come those methods can be chained together?

Comment: Note that `.pipe()` is deprecated, and `.then()` should be used instead.

Comment: thanks Barmar, I just figured it out. Actually to chain the pipes, I don't even need to pass anything along. I was able to chain the empty pipes together like this: .pipe().pipe().pipe(dosomething());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions called by `.pipe()` are not requred to return a `Deferred` or `Promise`. From the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.pipe/)

> These filter functions can return a new value to be passed along to the piped promise's done() or fail() callbacks, or they can return another observable object (Deferred, Promise, etc) which will pass its resolved / rejected status and values to the piped promise's callbacks.

In your code, since they don't have `return` statements, it's equivalent to `return undefined;`, and this is taken as the "new value to be passed along".

Comment: Nice explanation, this is really what I have overlooked. thanks a lot!

Comment: The funny thing is, there's a couple places that they are putting code like this: var a = function(){new $.Deferred().resolve();}; ....pipe(a()).pipe()..., totally make no sense to me.